# how to get value of checkbox in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a checkbox in Google sheet sidebar which has a form with a checkbox field.

Regardless of whether i check the checkbox or not, i get the value as "on".

I need to know whether the checkbox was checked or not

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

            <form>
    <div>
    <p>
          <label>
            <input name="item" id="Agree" type="checkbox" class="red"/>
            <span>Agree</span>

          </label>
        </p>
        </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">

            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" id="btn">Generate
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>

        </div>
        </form>

       <script>

                var agreeValue = document.getElementById("Agree")


                document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addRecord);

                function addRecord() {
                var data = {
                agreeValue               : Agree.value
                };


                google.script.run.appendData(data);
                }





    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to confirm the checkbox by `on` and `off`, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
var data = {
  agreeValue: Agree.value
};
```

#### To:

```
var data = {
  agreeValue: agreeValue.checked ? "on" : "off" // or Agree.checked ? "on" : "off"
};
```

- By this modification, when the checkbox is checked and unchecked, `data` becomes `{agreeValue: "on"}` and `{agreeValue: "off"}`, respectively.

#### Note:

- When `var data = {agreeValue: agreeValue.checked}` is used, you can retrieve the value of checkbox as a boolean.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, appreciate your help, I tried with this change, but it still give me only "on" as the value regardless of whether I check the box or not.

Comment: @Gela Ram Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. Because in my environment, the modified script works. So can you provide your current script for replicating your current issue? If you can do, please update your question. By this, I would like to confirm your issue and think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you so much, are you using Google Apps Script editor to run it?

Comment: @Gela Ram Thank you for replying. I couldn't understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I am using this script in the Google Apps Script editor to run, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ and it does not work, so thought to ask you where did you run the modification you suggested?

Comment: @Gela Ram Thank you for replying. I couldn't understand about your replying. Can you explain the detail flow for executing the script? From your script of your question, I had thought that the HTML is opened by a dialog, sidebar and Web Apps. Is my understanding correct? And also, can you provide the whole script including Google Apps Script for opening the HTML? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Gela Ram In order to resolve your issue, your cooperation is required, because in my environment, the modified script works at a dialog, sidebar and Web Apps. If you can provide the information for replicating your issue, I would like to confirm about it. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file enter code like this. The checkbox is now a Boolean

```
function addRecord() {
                var data = document.getElementsById("agree")[0].checked;

                google.script.run.appendData(data);
}
```

Then in the server side script place the `data` parameter in the condition of the If statement like this, since the condition of a if statement is in essence a boolean which you are pulling from you're html checkbox input.

```
if (data) {
   //code to execute if checkbox is checked
} else {
   //code to execute if NOT checked
}
```